# The function $P(x)=-0.09x^3 + 1.89x^2 +9x$ where $x \in [0,25]$ is given, find the following

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

A world wide distributor of basketballs determines that the yearly profit $P$, in thousands of dollars, earned the sale of $x$ thousand basketballs can be modelled by the function $P(x)=-0.09x^3 + 1.89x^2 +9x$ where $x \in [0,25]$.

a) Determine the average rate of change of profit earned on the sale of from

$\quad$ i) $2000$ to $6000$ basketballs

$\quad$ ii) $16000$ to $20000$ basketballs

b) Estimate the instantaneous rate of change of profit earned on the sale of

$\quad$ i) $5000$ basketballs

$\quad$ ii) $18000$ basketballs

Using the formula $(P(6000)-P(4000))/6000-4000$
I was able to solve for (a) and (b) but my answers don't align with the textbook. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I also don't know where to put $x \in [0,25]$.

Comment: It should be for example $\frac{P(6)-P(2)}{6-2}$ since $x$ ix measured in thousands of balls. And the answer is in thousands of dollars per  thousand balls. If you want it in some other unit you will have to convert.

Comment: Ive given that a try, it was closer but it still didn't match the textbooks $19, 440 answer for part i of a

Comment: It is $6$ and $2$ not $6$ and $4$.

Answer (score 0):

a. The average rate of change is $\frac{P(b)-P(a)}{b-a}$:

i. $2000$ basketballs $\to$ $x=2$. $6000$ basketballs $\to$ $x=6$.
$$\frac{P(b)-P(a)}{b-a}=\frac{P(6)-P(2)}{6-2}=\frac{(-0.09(6)^3 + 1.89(6)^2 + 9(6))-(-0.09(2)^3 + 1.89(2)^2 + 9(2))}{6-2}=\frac{(102.6)-(24.84)}{6-2}=\frac{77.76}{4}=\boxed{19.44}$$

I think what you may have done is to forget to divide the number of basketballs by $1000$ to find $x$ (the polynomial gives the profit for an input of $x$ thousand basketballs). I tried using the formula without dividing by $1000$ (i.e., calculating $\frac{P(6000)-P(2000)}{6000-2000}$ and I got the answer that you got.

Can you figure it out now?

Comment: Yup! Thanks a ton. For some reason i was subbing in 4k instead of 2k which was throwing me off

Comment: I see that you subbed in 4000 in the question now that you mention it. I didn't notice that before!